# Right click option to open a Bootstrap 'btn-link' span in a new tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am having a span with the Bootstrap 'btn-link' class applied on it. Here is the code:

```
<span class="btn-link">some text</span>
```

Now, I want the user to get the option to "Open in new tab" when he right clicks on the "span" element. By default, this isn't happening. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event with your element, and check the event. If it is right click then show the Menu, with your options.

Eg:

```
$("#test").on("mousedown",function(event) {
   if (event.which == 3) {
      // write your code to show the Menu with options.
      alert("right clicked!");
   }
});
```